# Resolving error with merging multiple Pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have been using this code to merge multiple Pandas dataframes in Python:

```
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce

dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5]
df_final = reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on='date'), dfs)
```

It is now giving me this error:

```
TypeError: Can only merge Series or DataFrame objects, a <class 'list'> was passed
```

How could I fix this?